# how can i add tab bar controller to my middle of my app with navigation controller

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I am developing simple app in iOS 7. I need to put a tab bar controller in my middle of my app - middle meaning the first 2 views containing signup and signin view with navigation controller. After login, my home view will be displayed. I want to show tab bar controller on my home view.

Please help me with my first app.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: set tab bar hidden for login/signup view. simple!

Comment: can you please clean up your writing? It is all over the place.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you will need to go back to Signin if you signout within the app, it would make more sense to keep Home View separate from the Signin View. And if you signin, you just change the root view controller to the Home View.

If you need to have Push Segue between Signin and Home, you can use Tabbar inside Home View and adjust it to do what UITabViewController does and still live in the medium that "it is a view controller."

Comment: at starting i have set the navigation controller

Comment: Gasim and Fawad masud bros thanks for your support i have crack that thanks for your suggestion and sorry for my grammar